# Is there a VS Code extension to jump to a VUE function

Tags: visual-studio-code

Company asking me to move from `WebStorm` to `VS Code` which is fine as I have used it many years ago but I was wondering if there is an extension to jump to a function call in any file.

**I.E**

In WS for my `VUE` app, if I add `@click`, `@paste` etc, to my `VUE` `HTML` file and then have a `function` in a `mixin` located in a different folder structure (or even the same file), currently (in WS) I can click it and it jumps to the `function`

Can this be done via the extensions in `VS code` at all and if so whats the extension called.

I have set up a test project when I installed `VS Code` and added a simple `JavaScript` `onclick` but it doesn't jump to my test `function`, even it's in the same file.

```
<input id="telNumField" class="form-control" type="search" :value="pdTelNo" @input="pdTelNoInput" @paste="telNoPaste" placeholder="Enter a contact number" v-telNoInput>

pdTelNoInput(value) {
    this.pdTelNo  = value.srcElement.value;
},

telNoPaste () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let originalTelNo = this.pdTelNo;
        let newTelNum = originalTelNo.replace(/\D/g, '');
        this.pdTelNo = newTelNum;
     }, 1)
 }
```

I found this highly beneficial to use in `WebStorm` so wondering if there is an extension in `VS Code`

Comment: @gama11 Why have you removed my VS-Code-Extension tag. The question is clearly about asking if there is an extension available and if so the name of it as there could be a few. I have added it back as it is a valid tag

Comment: Because that's not what the tag is for, it's for extension development. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vscode-extensions/info "Questions about extension usage should use tag [visual-studio-code]"

Comment: I'm not sure of any vs code extension but for default vs code, no. Unfortunately, you have to manually search for the function.